# Add a main drawer to a button in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter and I need to add the main drawer of the app to a button as you can see in the below picture(This is the upper section of the UI of the app)

[image]

Any ideas of having the main drawer apply to a button instead of having it normally assign it to the app bar. (This mobile app doesn't have an app bar)

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildWidgetAlbumCover(mediaQuery),
           getMainContentWidget(mediaQuery),
          _buildWidgetMenu(mediaQuery),
          _buildWidgetFloatingActionButton(mediaQuery),
            Drawer(
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                children: <Widget>[
                  DrawerHeader(
                    child: Text('Drawer Header'),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Item 1'),
                    onTap: () {
                    },
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Item 2'),
                    onTap: () {
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildWidgetMenu(MediaQueryData mediaQuery) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 2.0,
        top: mediaQuery.padding.top + 2.0,

      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.menu,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 25,
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
//            onPressed: () => scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O03T.jpg)
This is output which I get after having this code. This drawer can't even change or as it is fixed one. I want the normal drawer which is also attached to the _buildWidgetMenu instead of the app bar drawer.

Comment: always show some code

Comment: Tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: added the code snippets which i tried so far @Ashok

Answer (score 0):

If youre using a sacffold it has a drawer property that you can make use of  eg [cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/drawer)

```
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
  body: Center(child: Text('My Page!')),
  drawer: Drawer(...
```

opening your drawer from button clicks

```
 var scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
//required key 
     Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        drawer: new Drawer(
          child: new ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,...

             body:Center(..
                       IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
//open drawer
                onPressed: () => scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
          ),
```